# Closure of a conormal bundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm trying to compute the closure of the conormal space to a stratum in a stratified variety.  I'm getting an answer that I can't make sense of, so I thought I would ask for help here to get myself sorted out.  I'll describe what I tried so that someone can point out what I'm doing wrong.

Let $X = V(z^2 + xy) \subseteq\mathbb{A}^{3}$, stratified as $X = \left\{0\right\}\cup \left\{(x,y,z)\neq (0,0,0):\,z^2+xy = 0\right\}$.  Call the strata $S$ and $S'$, respectively.

Since $T_{(0,0,0)} S = 0$, we must have $T^*_{S}\mathbb{A}^{3} = \left\{(0,0,0,\xi_x,\xi_y,\xi_z) \in T^*\mathbb{A}^3\right\}$.

The tangent space to a point $(x,y,z) \in S'$ is given by:

$T_{(x,y,z)}S' = \ker d(z^2+xy) = \mathrm{span}_{\mathbb{C}}\langle x\partial_x+y\partial_y+z\partial_z, -2z\partial_y +x\partial_z, -2z\partial_x + y\partial_z\rangle$

The conormal space of $S'$ should be the row space of $d(z^2+xy) = y\,dx+x\,dy+2z\,dz$ because this covector annihilates a basis of $T_{(x,y,z)}S'$.  I want to find explicit equations which cut $T_{S'}^{*}\mathbb{A}^{3}$ out of $T^{*}\mathbb{A}^{3}$.  I thought I should get these equations by applying a covector $\xi = \xi_x\,dx + \xi_y\,dy + \xi_z\,dz$ to the three vectors which span $T_{(x,y,z)}S'$, together with the original equation cutting out $X$:

$\overline{T^{*}_{S'}\mathbb{A}^{3}} ``='' V(xy+z^2, x\xi_x + y\xi_y + z\xi_z, -2z\xi_y + x\xi_z, -2z\xi_x + y\xi_z)$

I put the equality in quotes because I think it's false.  Here is where I see a problem.

*Definition*: $\xi \in T_{S}^{*}\mathbb{A}^{3}$ is called degenerate if $\xi \in \overline{T^{*}_{S'}\mathbb{A}^{3}}$.

*Proposition* (Goresky-Macpherson, p.44): The set of degenerate covectors is a conical subvariety of $T_{S}^{*}\mathbb{A}^{3}$ with codimension $\geq 1$

If I assume that $\overline{T^{*}_{S'}\mathbb{A}^{3}}$ is given by the collection of equations I wrote down, then this contains the entire fiber of $T^{*}\mathbb{A}^{3}$ over $(0,0,0)$, which would imply that every covector in $T_S^{*}\mathbb{A}^{3}$ is degenerate.  In light of the proposition this must be impossible.  So what am I doing wrong?